# How to load a local Docker image in Minikube running on CRI-O?

Tags: docker, minikube, cri-o

To build and run a Docker image in Minikube running on the Docker container runtime, all I have to do is this:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
docker build -t some/tag .
```

Minikube will find the image.

But if I run Minikube in cri-o mode, this doesn't work, as expected. Is there a way to load a local Docker image and use that? In theory, any OCI-compliant container image should work?

Also, I'm on macOS if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the official way for Minikube is apparently the `registry` addon:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/registry/insecure/

Sounds great, unfortunately K8S refused to pull images from localhost:5000, I had to use the `registry-proxy-ip:80` prefix in the image spec to convince it to pull. 
I filed an issue here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6012

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
podman build -t some/tag .
```

Work for you?

Not really sure of the environment.
On the VM you can also do something like

```
podman pull docker-daemon:some/tag
```

which would populate the cri-o storage.

Skopeo has similar commands.

Comment: Podman sounds interesting, never used it. But doesn't run on mac apparently? https://github.com/containers/libpod/issues/4364#issuecomment-547426263